# How to extract the text between two patterns using REGEX perl

Tags: regex, perl

In the following lines how can I store the lines between "**Description:**" and "**Tag:**" in a variable using REGEX PERL and what would be a good datatype to use, string or list or something else?

(I am trying to write a program in Perl to extract the information of a text file with Debian package information and convert it into a RDF(OWL) file(ontology).)

**Description:** library for decoding ATSC A/52 streams (development)
 liba52 is a free library for decoding ATSC A/52 streams. The A/52 standard is
 used in a variety of applications, including digital television and DVD. It is
 also known as AC-3.

This package contains the development files.
Homepage: http://liba52.sourceforge.net/

**Tag:** devel::library, role::devel-lib

The code I have written so far is:

```
#!/usr/bin/perl
open(DEB,"Packages");
open(ONT,">>debianmodelling.txt");

$i=0;
while(my $line = <DEB>)
{

    if($line =~ /Package/)
    {
        $line =~ s/Package: //;
        print ONT '  <package rdf:ID="instance'.$i.'">';
        print ONT    '    <name rdf:datatype="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema#string">'.$line.'</name>'."\n";
    }
elsif($line =~ /Priority/)
{
    $line =~ s/Priority: //;
    print ONT '    <priority rdf:datatype="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema#string">'.$line.'</priority>'."\n";
}

elsif($line =~ /Section/)
{
    $line =~ s/Section: //;
    print ONT '    <Section rdf:datatype="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema#string">'.$line.'</Section>'."\n";
}

elsif($line =~ /Maintainer/)
{
    $line =~ s/Maintainer: //;
    print ONT '    <maintainer rdf:datatype="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema#string">'.$line.'</maintainer>'."\n";
}

elsif($line =~ /Architecture/)
{
    $line =~ s/Architecture: //;
    print ONT '    <architecture rdf:datatype="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema#string">'.$line.'</architecture>'."\n";
}
elsif($line =~ /Version/)
{
    $line =~ s/Version: //;
    print ONT '    <version rdf:datatype="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema#string">'.$line.'</version>'."\n";
}
elsif($line =~ /Provides/)
{
    $line =~ s/Provides: //;
    print ONT '    <provides rdf:datatype="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema#string">'.$line.'</provides>'."\n";
}
elsif($line =~ /Depends/)
{
    $line =~ s/Depends: //;
    print ONT '    <depends rdf:datatype="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema#string">'.$line.'</depends>'."\n";
}
elsif($line =~ /Suggests/)
{
    $line =~ s/Suggests: //;
    print ONT '    <suggests rdf:datatype="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema#string">'.$line.'</suggests>'."\n";
}

elsif($line =~ /Description/)
{
    $line =~ s/Description: //;
    print ONT '    <Description rdf:datatype="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema#string">'.$line.'</Description>'."\n";
}
elsif($line =~ /Tag/)
{
    $line =~ s/Tag: //;
    print ONT '    <Tag rdf:datatype="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema#string">'.$line.'</Tag>'."\n";
    print ONT '  </Package>'."\n\n";
}
$i=$i+1;
}
```

Comment: Since choosing the best datatype is completely dependent on your intended use of the data, you'll need to provide some explanation of your goal.

Comment: @Rob Raisch: I apologise for missing to place the question at the begining. Is this ok?

Comment: @Rob I just need to store in a variable to copy it to a file.

Comment: ok, just found out, actually I have been asking questions about the start of big projects so wasn't easy to test all the answers in a short time.

Answer (score 18, accepted):

```
my $desc = "Description:";
my $tag  = "Tag:";

$line =~ /$desc(.*?)$tag/;
my $matched = $1;
print $matched;
```

---

or

---

```
my $desc = "Description:";
my $tag  = "Tag:";

my @matched = $line =~ /$desc(.*?)$tag/;
print $matched[0];
```

---

or

---

```
my $desc = "Description:";
my $tag  = "Tag:";

(my $matched = $line) =~ s/$desc(.*?)$tag/$1/;
print $matched;
```

---

### Additional

---

If your Description and Tag may be on separate lines, you may need to use the `/s` modifier, to treat it as a single line, so the `\n` won't wreck it.  Example:

```
$_=qq{Description:foo 
      more description on 
      new line Tag: some
      tag};
s/Description:(.*?)Tag:/$1/s; #notice the trailing slash
print;
```

Comment: How would exactly a HTML parser reduce the effort? I am sorry to ask a novice question as I am totally new to the world of semantic web.

Comment: Excuse me, I thought you were parsing an XML document.  I've removed that from my answer.  See the above.  Still, it looks like you're building an XML document, so perhaps you could use an HTML/XML package after all.

Comment: +1. However, the third instance (`(my $matched = $line) =~ s/$desc(.*?)$tag/$1/;`) did not work for me; it simply stripped the contents of `$desc` and `$tag` from `$line`; consequently, `$matched` contained the remaining contents of the line.

Comment: @user001 yeah I don't know what I was thinking then, most of these examples were off the top of the noggin' most likely when I was traveling.  `s/$desc(.*?)$tag/$1/` is doing a replace. For that to have any affect, the rest of the line needs to be included: `s/.*$desc(.*?)$tag.*/$1/` (I think this would work)

Answer (score 4):

Assuming:

```
my $example; # holds the example text above
```

You could:

```
(my $result=$example)=~s/^.*?\n(Description:)/$1/s; # strip up to first marker

$result=~s/(\nTag:[^\n]*\n).+$/$1/s; # strip everything after second marker line
```

Or

```
(my $result=$example)=~s/^.*?\n(Description:.+?Tag:[^\n]*\n).*$/$1/s;
```

Both assume the Tag: value is contained on a single line.

If this is not the case, you might try:

```
(my $result=$example)=~s/
    (                        # start capture
        Description:         # literal 'Description:'
        .+?                  # any chars (non-greedy) up to
        Tag:                 # literal 'Tag:'
        .+?                  # any chars up to
    )
    (?:                      # either
      \n[A-Z][a-z]+\:        #  another tagged value name 
    |                         # or
      $                       #  end of string
    )
/$1/sx;
```

Answer (score 3):

I believe that the problem is caused by using a line reading loop for data structured by paragraphs. If you can slurp the file into memory and and apply **split** with a captured delimiter, the processing will be much smoother:

```
#!/usr/bin/perl -w

use strict;
use diagnostics;
use warnings;

use English;

# simple sample sub
my $printhead = sub {
  printf "%5s got the tag '%s ...'\n", '', substr( shift, 0, 30 );
};
# map keys/tags? to functions
my %tagsoups = (
    'PackageName' => sub {printf "%5s got the name '%s'\n", '', shift;}
  , 'Description' => sub {printf "%5s got the description:\n---------\n%s\n----------\n", '', shift;}
  , 'Tag'         => $printhead
);
# slurp Packages (fallback: parse using $INPUT_RECORD_SEPARATOR = "Package:")
open my $fh, "<", './Packages-00.txt' or die $!;
local $/; # enable localized slurp mode
my $all = <$fh>;
my @pks = split /^(Package):\s+/ms, $all;
close $fh;
# outer loop: Packages
for (my $p = 1, my $n = 0; $p < scalar @pks; $p +=2) {
  my $blk = "PackageName: " . $pks[$p + 1];
  my @inf = split /\s*^([\w-]+):\s+/ms, $blk;
  printf "%3d %s named %s\n", ++$n, $pks[$p], $inf[ 2 ];
  # outer loop: key-value-pairs (or whatever they are called)
  for (my $x = 1; $x < scalar @inf; $x += 2) {
      if (exists($tagsoups{$inf[ $x ]})) {
          $tagsoups{$inf[ $x ]}($inf[$x + 1]);
      }
  }
}
```

output for a shortened Packages file from my Ubuntu Linux:

```
  3 Package named abrowser-3.5-branding
      got the PackageName:
---------
abrowser-3.5-branding
----------
      got the Description:
---------
dummy upgrade package for firefox-3.5 -> firefox
 This is a transitional package so firefox-3.5 users get firefox on
 upgrades. It can be safely removed.
----------
  4 Package named casper
      got the PackageName:
---------
casper
----------
      got the Description:
---------
Run a "live" preinstalled system from read-only media
----------
      got the Tag:
---------
admin::boot, admin::filesystem, implemented-in::shell, protocol::smb, role::plugin, scope::utility, special::c
ompletely-tagged, works-with-format::iso9660
----------
```

Using a hash for the functions to apply to the extracted parts will keep the details of generating xml out of the parser loops.